# php how to bind values of 2 arrays with each other

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

For a flat file blog i read all the blog files (.txt files) with glob.
Each `.txt` file has different lines. A .txt file looks like this:

```
id_20200514222532 // id line (0 line)
club            
uploads/12.jpg
soccer           // title line (3rd line)
comment goes here 
14 May 2020 22:25 
john              
soccer,barcelona  
194               
4                // likes line (9th line, number of likes)
```

What i am trying to achieve: output only the 5 titles with the most likes!

This is what i have so far:

```
$files = glob("data/articles/*.txt"); // read all files in dir articles
$title_lines = array();
$like_lines = array();
foreach($files as $file) { // Loop the files in the directory
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $title_lines[] = strtolower($lines[3]); // grab title line  
    $like_lines[] = $lines[9]; // grab like line
    // $title_lines contains all values of the titles
    // $like_lines contains all values of likes

    // output now only the 5 titles with the most likes

}
```

So my output should be something like below:

```
Soccer (4) // 4 likes
Swim   (3) // 3 likes
Baseball (3) // 3 likes
Volleybal (2) // 2 likes
Athletics (1) // 1 like
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stores the like slightly different, it uses the title as the likes array index, builds a list of all of the files and then reverse sorts the list (maintaining the index using `arsort()`).  Then uses `array_slice()` to get the top 5...

```
$like_lines = [];
$files = glob("data/articles/*.txt"); // read all file sin dir articles
$like_lines = array();
foreach($files as $file) { // Loop the files in the directory
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $like_lines[strtolower($lines[3])] = $lines[9]; // grab like line
}
// Sort in descending number of likes
arsort($like_lines);
// Extract top 5
$top5 = array_slice($like_lines, 0, 5);

print_r($like_lines);
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i was looking for.